# Error mounting a CF card

Tags: mount

How can I fix this? It showed up when mounting a CF card on Ubuntu Linux.

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/mohamed/1258-C98A: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/mohamed/1258-C98A"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock

Comment: What is the result of `parted -l`?

Comment: It didn't output anything! It displayed the prompt.

Comment: [Sorry](http://xkcd.com/149/), what is the output of `sudo parted -l`?

Comment: "/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label"

Comment: Have you (can you) formatted the drive?

Comment: I have formatted the drive, and the output of the previous command: `Model: Generic Compact Flash (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2012MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2012MB  2011MB  primary  fat32`

Comment: I should mention that I formatted the drive with gParted. After format, there is a round 'i' mark near the partition in gParted.

Comment: I suspect you should have used fdisk (and MBR)... I have never seen a multi-terabyte CF card. But, since parted recognizes the partition I have to ask if you can mount it now?

Comment: Now I can see the drive, but I can't see it's content. The CF card is 2 Gigabytes only. The Long message I posted in the question description is still there, with deffirent numbers after /media/mohamed/

Comment: You formatted it, so what content? Also, it's starting to sound like the card is **bad**.

Comment: Oh, yes. There is no content, but I don't see a blank page either. I guess the card might be faulted like you said. I ran sudo dosfsck /dev/sdb and it returned: "only 1 or 2 FATs are supported, not 251".

Comment: Use `fsck.vfat`.

Comment: If I entered `sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sdb` the output is `Currently, only 1 or 2 FATs are supported, not 251`. If entering `sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sdb1` the output is `File system has 490302 clusters but only space for 359422 FAT entries.`